# Is there a way to debug rendering problems in a famo.us app?

Tags: javascript, rendering, famo.us

Is there a way to turn debugging on or some command to show us rendering problems when using famo.us?

Log statements would be helpful or any other way of telling us what is going when the app is being rendered.

**EDIT: Here are the rendering problems I have seen so far**

1- **Layout is inconsistent across browsers** (Not even talking about IE yet!!!!).

*Safari 7.02:*

[image]

*Chrome35:*

[image]

*Android Firefox 29:*

[image]

2- **Scrolling with famo.us is basically screwed.**

I have 3 main sections my app (website):

- Header (which is a ScrollContainer with 4 surfaces).
- Footer (Which is a ScrollContainer with 1 surface).
- Content (2 ScrollContainers on the left side and 2 ScrollContainers inside a Deck component on the right side. Each text/paragraph is a surface in its respective ScrollContainer).

Now, if you [go to my app](http://mbasim.me), you will notice that the scrolling is screwed and I have no idea why! I don't even know how I can debug this mess.

**P.S:** The code is left un-minified and with comments on purpose.

But wait there is more. Scrolling is confusing to the user as **the user has no idea that this view is scrollable because no scrollbars are visible**. [You can even see that on the famo.us demo page](https://famo.us/demos). Go and try to scroll :). The only way you can scroll is if you go to the left side of the page ...

3- The Deck component seem to arrange the cards randomly on initial load based on the browser! As if things aren't already screwed enough. See screenshot below:

**Chrome35 Desktop renders the green card first**:
[image]

**FF29 Desktop renders the red card first**:
[image]

With all the above issues. I have no idea how to fix them or why they are happening.
List of things that will help me as a developer debug problems with famo.us:

1. Enable some debug logging when using components.
2. Throw JS errors when using components incorrectly.
3. Warn me about potential layout problems if using components with known issues.
4. Have better documentation. I basically read your code base to understand how to use something because the famo.us docs is not adding much value without having examples whereas your open source code does.
5. More articles talking about layout and page structure. This is a fundamental thing. If we can't get this right, there is no point playing with animations on a page that is not viewable correctly!

I have also noticed that FF29 on Desktop lags when I interact with the Deck of cards whereas on Chrome it doesn't. So backing up your 60fps claim across devices would be a good start. Show us performance metrics and comparisons to prove that claim.

I really want to use famo.us and I will hopefully contribute some fixes if I get some time but [this is currently how I feel about famo.us](https://medium.com/programming-is-a-nightmare/shits-fucked-up-de07d5ff5415).

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to debug exactly ?

Comment: Andrew from famo.us here. We'd love to hear more about the problems you need to debug and debugging utilities/features you would find useful.

Comment: @AndrewDeAndrade sure. I have added the debug problems I have seen so far and what debugging features would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be great if there was something that gave more info. Like a famoushint or something. I use jshint that at least helps with the common JavaScript errors.

Also, this has saved me a few times as well. http://famo.us/guides/pitfalls

But I agree it is a little buggy at this point, I've been having trouble with the Scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no render specific debugging tools in Famo.us..

There are a couple of things I do when I run into problems..

1) Use javascripts 'debugger' command to stop the execution of the code and inspect the environment..

```
debugger;
```

2) Use a class that you can easily search in the surface you want to inspect. This class would contain no style but be unique enough to be used as an identifier to find the element quickly within the DOM tree.

```
var suspiciousSurface = new Surface({
    size:[200,200],
    classes: ['my-debug-class']
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh that's a shame. Yes, I already use debugging tools like FF/Chrome dev tools to debug my problems. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll wait a bit before accepting in case someone knows something more about this.

Answer (score 0):

a famo.us app is fundamentally a javascript app, so the same techniques apply http://berzniz.com/post/78260747646/5-javascript-debugging-tips-youll-start-using-today

About the rendering, it is OK to inspect the DOM. If your scene is not too complex, you can quickly figure out which DIV your surfaces map to.

You can also outline a particular surface  as @johntraver suggests, or also outline all the surfaces : in you CSS, add :

```
.famous-surface {
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```